# Unexpected result of listcomprehension when "or" occurs in the restriction

Tags: rascal

The following result appears to me as a strange result.

```
rascal> [x|int x<-[0..3],x==2||x==2];

list[int]: [2,2]
```

I expected this.

```
rascal> [x|int x<-[0..3],(x==2||x==2)?true:false];
list[int]: [2]
```

Comment: Are you happy with the answer Bert?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed a bit strange but consistent.

The answer is that the "loop" iterates for every time it can make the conditions true, backtracking over commas , and over && and || and !, but not (yet) over ?:, function calls, and other operators. So,

```
x==2 || x==2
```

can be made true in two ways and that is why you get 2 answers, and with the ?: it only tries once.

This iteration behavior is necessary, since we would want this result as well:

```
rascal>[x|int x<-[0..3],x==2||x==3];
list[int]: [2,3]
```